# Start java executable via PHP on windows

Tags: java, php, wamp

I try to start a java file via PHP. I created a .bat file named **start_selenium_server.bat**.

This is the content: `java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="drivers/geckodriver.exe" selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -port 4444`

The folder `drivers` is in the same folder as the .bat file, which is in the root directory of my project.

The file *selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar* is also in the same directory.

This is how I try to start it:

```
    $out = array();
    $outvar = "";
    exec("start_selenium_server.bat", $out, $outvar);

    if ($outvar == 0) {
        return redirect()->back()->with("message", "Selenium Server wurde gestartet.")
                                 ->with("status", "success");
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with("message", "Selenium Server konnte nicht gestartet werden!")
                                 ->with("status", "error");
    }
```

But the site just loads forever and nothing happens.

[image]

**Edit:** I noticed that a `cmd.exe` and `conhost.exe` task is getting spawned in the task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/de/function.proc-open.php).

```
    $descriptorspec = array(
       0 => array("file", "tmp/stdin.log", "a"),
       1 => array("file", "tmp/stdout.log", "a"),
       2 => array("file", "tmp/stderr.log", "a")
    );

    $process = proc_open ('START /B start_selenium_server.bat', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

   if (is_resource($process)) {

        $response = proc_close($process);


        if ($response == 0) {
            return redirect()->back()->with("message", "Kommando wurde ausgeführt.")
                                     ->with("status", "success");
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with("message", "Error !")
                                     ->with("status", "warning")
        }

    }
```

The server starts now, but I need to improve this code to check wheter or not it was successfull and show it to the user.

Answer (score 2):

That seems logical to me, the server starts, and runs, and doesn't end.

You probaby just want to background the process using `&`.

```
exec("/path/to/script &");
```

Of course, you are using windows, which brings it's own set of headaches to the table. The solution I gave you is for a Linux based system (the default expected config), so you'll have to find out how to get a windows executable to run in the background.

> UPDATE

I just had a look, and found this:

```
START /B program
```

So I think what you need is:

```
exec('START /B start_selenium_server.bat');
```

Of course the down side to this is that your system is now coupled to Windows.

> Another update

This should work on both Linux and Windows. Note we don't use exec in Windows, so give this a try!

```
if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
     pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
 } 
 else { 
     exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does still load forever.